# php multi-demenional array from mysql then using str_replace

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, str-replace

I have searched on Google, however, I still couldn't find out the best solution for my array problem.

**Expected:**

> *1.* User post a string to server **->**
>
> *2.* We filter the string and replace those words which match the data stored in the database **->**
>
> *3* Insert the string which has been replaced by us into the database.

**Current complete:**

> *1.* datatable with columns named `(1)ID (2)alias (3)replacement`
>
> *2.* A form let users post the string `(post by jquery-ajax)`
>
> *3.* A function return all results from the table in array

**Test this class without reading results from Db:**

> **Class**
>
> ```
> class replace{
>
>     function tag($_input){
>           $definition = array('morning' => 'Good morning!', 'nowTime' => time());
>           foreach ($definition as $key => $value)   
>               $_input= str_replace('{{' . $key . '}}', $value, $_input); 
>           return $_input;` 
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> **Using method**
>
> ```
> $replace= new replace();
> $_input = '{{morning}} everyone, current unix time is {{nowTime}}' ;
> echo $replace->tag($_input);
> ```
>
> **Output result (successful)**
>
> Good morning everyone, current unix time is 1417758157

However, when I tried to use the array ouput by the database to replace `$definition`

**Problem happened:**

> **Array output from db**
>
> array
>
> ```
>  0 =>
>    array
>      'ID' => 445
>      'alias' => 'morning'
>      'replacement' => 'Good morning'
>  1 =>
>    array
>      'ID' => 446
>      'alias' => 'nowTime'
>      'replacement' => time()
>  2 =>
>    array
>      'ID' => 447
>      'alias' => 'tommorowNow'
>      'replacement' => time()+86400
> ```
>
> **Tried**
>
> ```
>   function replace(){
>       // $tagEngine is the array ouput from Db
>       foreach ($tagEngine as $arrKey) {
>            $definition = array($arrKey['alias'] => $arrKey['replacement']);
>           return ($definition);   
>       };
>   }
> ```
>
> **But only returns the first result**
>
> array
>
> ```
>  'morning' => 'Good morning'
> ```

Moreover, I would like to ask how to complete the my expected result as I mentioned first.
I'm confused where to put my str_replace in the `$replace()`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me some things need to be altered. First of all, use the definitions in your class, not seperately (otherwise you are just using the class to store functions instead of for its 'object'-properties);

```
class replace {
    public $definitions;

    public function setDefinitions($definitions) {
        $this->definitions = $definitions;
    }

    public function tag($input) {
        if($this->definitions && is_array($this->definitions)) {
            foreach ($this->definitions as $definition) {
                if($defintion['alias'] == 'time') {
                    $input = str_replace('{{' . $definition['alias'] . '}}', date('Y-m-d'), $input);
                } else {
                    $input = str_replace('{{' . $definition['alias'] . '}}', $definition['replacement'], $input);
                }
            }
        }
        return $input;
    }
}
```

As you can see above, you can store the definitions from your database in the object and use them in the `tag()` public method.

Second, instead of using a function, just invoke the parsing of the string on the spot where you need it. Like so:

```
$replace = new replace();
$replace->setDefinitions($tagEngine);
$parsedString = $replace->tag('{{morning}} everyone, current unix time is {{nowTime}}');

echo $parsedString;
```

I haven't tested the code (so I hope I didn't make any mistakes).

Comment: Thank you! I just tried the class your provided and it ran successfully. There is one more question, how to echo the right script?
For example, `time()` can be ran in the **Test this class without reading results from Db**, so I can get the real unix time on the page,  and I guess that's because I set the `$definition` manually. However, when the `$definition` read from the table, I can only get the plain text _time()_ showed on my page. How to solve this kind of problem?
Thanks again.

Comment: @Mark I have updated the answer (class) with an extra conditional. Now, when you have the alias `{{time}}`, it makes sure it is translated to the current `yyyy-mm-dd`. Check the PHP reference for use of the `date()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php You can change `date()` into `time()` to get it the way you asked, but I think you meant something like this...

Comment: Thanks for answering, Richard! However, I definitely know how to convert the unix time to y/m/d. What I really mean is **I may stored some php script into the _replacement_ column, and when I use the alias, the script will be ran and show on the page**
As I mentioned in the last comment, I can get the result like "147850154"  when I POST a string contains {{nowTime}}, but after adapting your class, The result only returns me "time()" which is expected to be the result of the script stored in the __replacement__ column.
Thank you!

Comment: First of all, mark this answer as the correct answer. Than create a new question in which you ask how to parse PHP data from a database-record (first perform a search to check if someone has already asked the question though!!). At StackOverflow we try to keep different questions as different questions ;)

Comment: Thanks for notice, I will do that later. New here and I will be the sponge to learn as much as I can.